# Recursive Map using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a data that needs to be recursive but I don't know how to implement it. Here is my data.
[image]

All I need to do is to look like this.

```
[
      {
        id: 1,
        label: 'Satisfied customers',
        children: [
          {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Good food',
            icon: 'restaurant_menu',
            children: [

              { id: 3, label: 'Quality ingredients'},
              { id: 4, label: 'Good recipe' }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            label: 'Good service',
            icon: 'room_service',
            children: [
              { id: 6, label: 'Prompt attention' },
              { id: 7, label: 'Professional waiter' }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 8,
            label: 'Pleasant surroundings',
            icon: 'photo',
            children: [
              {
                id: 9,
                label: 'Happy atmosphere (not tickable)',
                tickable: false,
              },
              {
                id: 10,
                label: 'Good table presentation (disabled node)',
                disabled: true,
              },
              {
                id: 11,
                label: 'Pleasing decor',
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: 12,
            label: 'Extra information (has no tick)',
            noTick: true,
            icon: 'photo'
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            label: 'Forced tick strategy (to "strict" in this case)',
            tickStrategy: 'strict',
            icon: 'school',
            children: [
              {
                id: 14,
                label: 'Happy atmosphere',
              },
              {
                id: 15,
                label: 'Good table presentation',
              },
              {
                id: 16,
                label: 'Very pleasing decor',
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

My code doesn't works... it's just a map without any recursion.

```
categories.map(e => {
        console.log(e.all_children)
        return {
          id: e.id,
          label: e.name,
          children: _.values(e).map(v => {
              return { id: v.id, label: e.name }
          })
        }
      })
```

I don't really know how to do it. If you have any idea on how to do it please help me. I've been searching how to do it using lodash but I can't find any relevant code. I'm not very good in javascript.

Comment: Can you post your input data as *text*, not an image, so that we can try to work with it? See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify a function for later mapping inside of the callback.

```
const
    map = e => ({
        id: e.id,
        label: e.name,
        children: e.all_children.map(map) // recursive call
    }),
    tree = categories.map(map);
```

To get all properties without `all_children`, you could take [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for properties and separate just the children property for recursive mapping.

```
const
    map = ({ all_children = [], ...o }) => ({
        ...o,
        children: all_children.map(map) // recursive call
    }),
    tree = categories.map(map);
```